# AutoMapper for Nested inside Nested with Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, automapper

I am trying to AutoMapper to EF models which are nested inside nested. 
For Example in below code categorySrc, languageSrc, abstractSrc..etc and  categoryDest, languageDest, abstractDest ..etc classes are same.

Now I am trying to Map categorySrc to categoryDest, So I made like below, if throwing an error
 Is something I am doing wrong here?

```
  var categoryData = abstractContext.GetCategoryByCatId(catId);
        Mapper.CreateMap<Models.categoryDest, categorySource>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<languageDest, Models.languageSource>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<@abstractDest, Models.@abstractSrc>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<abstract_categoryDest, Models.abstract_categorySrc>();
        Mapper.CreateMap<questionDest, Models.questionSrc>();
        Mapper.CreateMap ... //For other objects
        Mapper.CreateMap ...//For other objects
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); //Error occurring here 
        var category = Mapper.Map<category,Models.category>(categoryData);
```

### Classes:

```
public partial class categoryDest
{

    public int category_id { get; set; }
    public int language_id { get; set; }
    public virtual languageDest language { get; set; }
}

public partial class languageDest
{
    public language()
    {
        this.abstracts = new HashSet<@abstractDest>();
        this.abstract_category = new HashSet<abstract_categoryDest>();
        this.categories = new HashSet<categoryDest>();
        this.questions = new HashSet<questionDest>();
    }

    public int language_id { get; set; }
    public string language_name { get; set; }
    public string language_locale_code { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<@abstractDest> abstracts { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<abstract_categoryDest> abstract_category { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<categoryDest> categories { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<questionDest> questions { get; set; }
}


public partial class @abstractDest
    {
        public @abstract()
        {
            this.abstract_category = new HashSet<abstract_categoryDest>();
            this.abstract_fields = new HashSet<abstract_fieldsDest>();
            this.abstract_image = new HashSet<abstract_imageDest>();
            this.people = new HashSet<person>();
        }

        public int abstract_id { get; set; }
        public int language_id { get; set; }
        public string abstract_name { get; set; }      

        public virtual ICollection<abstract_categoryDest> abstract_category { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<abstract_fieldsDest> abstract_fields { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<abstract_imageDest> abstract_image { get; set; }
        public virtual languageDest language { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<personDest> people { get; set; }
    }
```

How to do this complex mapping?

Comment: Have a look here http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/03/11/efficient-querying-with-linq-automapper-and-future-queries/

Comment: What is the configuration validation error you're getting?